# How to call parent module constructors?

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I want to call the constructors of two modules I have included in a class, but I don't know how to do it.

```
module GameObject
  attr_reader :x, :y
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end
end

module Attackable
 attr_reader :health, :damage
 def initialize(health, damage)
   @health, @damage = health, damage
 end
end

class SuperMario
  include GameObject
  include Attackable
  def initialize(x, y, health, damage)
    .. how to call the above constructors?
  end
end
```

How do I call the constructor of Attackable and GameObject?

Comment: both `#initialize` do you want to call?

Comment: yes |enter15characters

Comment: Has the answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1):

As the way you can call the `module`'s methods explicitly in the class initializer as follows:

```
def initialize(x, y, health, damage)
   m = GameObject.instance_method( :initialize )
   m.bind(self).call( x, y )
   m = Attackable.instance_method( :initialize )
   m.bind(self).call( health, damage)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you come from the C++ world, where multiple inheritance is allowed... In short, Ruby only offers single inheritance, and doesn't allow to nitpick the parent method that you're calling. This makes what you're trying to achieve unweildy, to put it mildly. Modules aren't going to offer you any good workarounds -- even after accounting for `prepend` or `self.included` and the rest of the metaprogramming toolbox -- except in the specific set of cases where they have no name collisions.

What you *could* do is rename the initialize method so its logic in a function specific to its module, and call *that*. Aside: it's usually a code smell to define an `initialize` method in a module to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I learned something new today:

```
module B
  def cat(a) puts "in B, a = #{a}" end
end

module C
  def cat(a) puts "in C, a = #{a}"; super a+1; end
end

class A
  include B
  include C
  def cat(a) puts "in A, a = #{a}"; super a+1; end
end

A.new.cat(2)
# => in A, a = 2
# => in C, a = 3
# => in B, a = 4
```

Your question is not restricted to `initialize`, which is why I illustrated this behavior with a generic method.  I had expected the `includes` would just mix-in the other two `cat` methods, so the result would be the same as:

```
class D
  def cat(a) puts "in 1st, a = #{a}" end
  def cat(a) puts "in 2nd, a = #{a}"; super a+1; end
  def cat(a) puts "in 3rd, a = #{a}"; super a+1; end
end

D.new.cat(2)
# => in 3rd, a = 2
# => module.rb:24:in `cat': super: no superclass method `cat' for
#    #<D:0x007faadb99acb8> (NoMethodError) from module.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

I was puzzled by @sawa's comment about "super" and found I was wrong.  (I hope not everyone reading this will be thinking, "so what else is new?".)